# "Refuse anyone help" or "refuse to help anyone"

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

> My auntie would never refuse anyone help if they need it.

Can you explain "**anyone help**"? I think it should be: "**to help anyone**".

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?

Comment: @VarunNair Page 158, question 6, ISBN:9787560017235

Comment: ***Refuse*** can be used intransitively *(I asked to see her, but she refused)*, and transitively *(...but she refused **me**)*. But it can also be used *ditransitively* (with direct ***and*** indirect object), as in  *...but she refused **me an audience***.

Comment: The transitive form ("refuse him", "refuse her own daughter", "refuse anyone") can be very expressive - it has a emphasis on the human relationship, one person denying another's request. The "refuse to help" has more of a focus on the action that is not being taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My auntie would never refuse anyone help if they need it.

Refuse is a verb. If you want to make it explicitly clear, without possibility of misunderstanding, you could say "refuse to give", but as it is, anyone fluent in English will understand the meaning without the extra "to give".

"Help" is the direct object, the thing which is "given", or "not given", in this case where we are using "*refuse* to give".

"Anyone" is an indirect object identifying the person *to which* the "help" is "given" (or *not* given, in this case.) "Anyone" is located in the customary place for an indirect object, between the verb and the direct object.

So this sentence is grammatical, and people fluent in English would not mistake its meaning.

As Y. zeng proposes, *another* way to say it would be:

> My auntie would never refuse to help anyone if they need it.

Both are equally correct.

Answer (score 2):

> My auntie would never refuse anyone help if they need it.

is correct. You must notice that "anyone" and "help" are not together, as an expression. Actually, the structure is:

> - refuse
>
>   - anyone  => refuse anyone
>   - help  => refuse help

and **not**:

> - refuse
>
>   - anyone help

A more "standard" way to say the same thing would be:

> My auntie would never refuse **to help** anyone if they need it.

In this case, "**help**" changes from noun to verb.

Or:

> My auntie would never refuse **to offer help to** anyone if they need it.

"Help" remains noun (as in the original version), but a new verb is introuced (to offer). This is the closest in meaning to the original question.

Comment: Why anyone help does not mean anyone helps her instead of she help anyone.

Comment: Good point, I extended the answer.

Comment: I am curious for the reason of the downvote. Please provide an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the collocation from the Oxford Dictionary.

> "[transitive] to say that you will not allow something; to say that
>   you will not give or allow somebody something that they want or need
>   synonym ***deny***
>
> The authorities refused permission for the new housing development.
>
> He refused our request for an interview.
>
> ***The judge refused her application for bail.***
>
> refuse somebody something 
>   ***They refused him a visa.***"

To refuse anyone help is the usage given above in the dictionary.

"To refuse to help anyone" is fine, too.

So, to refuse + indirect object + direct object is fine.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/refuse1[refuse when it means deny](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/refuse1)

Comment: If I change you example slightly to *The judge refused her leave to appeal,* it seems to me this changes the more natural interpretation of the syntax from *monotransitive* (the thing he refused was ***her application***, where ***her*** simply qualifies ***application***), to *ditransitive* - he refused (to give) ***her*** something, that "something" being the indirect object ***leave to appeal***. But there's plenty of scope for *syntactic* (but not necessarily *semantic*) ambiguity with such constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am merely providing proof of concept for: refuse anyone [something], which means to deny. In practical terms ***here***, the two things have the same meaning: his auntie never refused anyone help and his auntie never refused to help anyone.

Comment: The issue is ***[mono]transitive*** vs ***di/bitransitive***. I'm inclined to parse your (her?) *application for bail* as the latter, but there are arguments on both sides for that one, as I pointed out.